# When can we be sure that the maximum of the harmonic mean of two functions is where we'd expect it to be?

Tags: real-analysis

If we have two functions, P(x) and R(x), where P is monotonically increasing and R is monotonically decreasing, and their curves cross, and we take the harmonic mean:

$$M(x) = \frac{2P(x)R(x)}{P(x)+R(x)}$$

in what circumstances can we expect the maximum of $M(x)$ to be at the point where $P(x) = R(x)$?

For example, is it enough for $P(x)$ and $R(x)$ to be continuous?

Here's an example of the data that prompted the question, and where F-measure is another name, used in information retrieval, for the harmonic mean.

[image: Example of data that prompted the question]

Comment: Why would you expect this?  Suppose that $P(x)$ increases steeply, as in $P(x)=10^6\, x$ on $[0,1]$.  Meanwhile, suppose $R(x)$ decreases gently, as in $10^{-6}e^{-x}$.    Clearly the average is, approximately, $\frac 12 P(x)$ which is maximized at the right hand endpoint.

Comment: Fair point. I'm revising the question - heavily.

Comment: The geometric mean is $\sqrt{PR}$, not divided by the sum of the two.  Your expression is the harmonic mean.

Answer (score 2):

**Note** this is an answer to a previous version of the question, where $M=(P+R)/2$. Had it all typed up and then the question changed... See "**Heh-heh**" below for an answer to the current version.

So suppose $M=(P+R)/2$.

If there *is* a point $x$ where the two curves cross and if $P\ge0$ and $R\ge0$ then $M(x)$ is actually within a factor of $2$ of being the *minimum* of $M$. (*Hence* $M(x)$ is close to the maximum if $P,R\le 0$.)

Indeed, if $t>x$ then $$M(t)\ge P(t)/2\ge P(x)/2=(P(x)+R(x))/4=M(x)/2;$$similarly if $t<x$.

**Heh-heh** It follows that if $P,R>0$ and $H$ is the harmonic mean then $H(x)$ is within a factor of $4$ of the maximum of $H$. Because the result above shows that $1/P(x)+1/R(x)$ is within a factor of $2$ of the minimum of $1/P+1/R$, and $H=2/(1/P+1/R)$.

This can actually be useful. My favorite example:

> > If $f,f'\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ then $\hat f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, and in fact $||\hat f||_1\le c(||f||_2||f'||_2)^{1/2}.$

Proof: For $A>0$ we have $$\int_{|t|<A}|\hat f(t)|\le(2A)^{1/2}||\hat f||_2=(2A)^{1/2}||f||_2.$$And since $||f'||_2^2=\int t^2|\hat f(t)|^2$ we get $$\int_{|t|>A}|\hat f(t)|\le\left(\int_{|t|>A}1/t^2\right)^{1/2}||f'||_2=(2/A)^{1/2}||f'||_2.$$Now set $A=||f'||_2/||f||_2$ and the result follows, with $c=2^{3/2}$.

(**Of course** we're free to set $A=||f'||_2/||f||_2$ even if we don't know that result about the minimum being essentially at the point where the two curves cross; that result reassures us that the value of $c$ we got is not totally stupid: we cannot get a *much* better $c$ from any other value of $A$.)

Comment: I'm sorry about changing the question. I'm new here and didn't realise someone might do what you did. Oddly enough, the two questions are related; it just seemed simpler at the time to rephrase it this way. And now I think I'd better not change it back!

Comment: @Blackjack It's ok. Newest version of the answer covers both versions.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just looking at the other reply at the moment. I'll then look at your one. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Looking at the first reply - before the heh-heh - I cannot in fact follow any of the inequalities you have put in the line following "Indeed, if t > x, " Can you explain?

Comment: @Blackjack Use the fact that $P$ is increasing and $R\ge0$: $M(t)=(P(t)+R(t))/2\ge P(t)/2\ge P(x)/2=(P(x)+R(x))/4$.

Comment: Thanks @David. Got it. Now thinking on...

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating wrt $M$ you find

$$M'(x) = 2\frac{(P'(x)R(x)+P(x)R'(x))(P(x)+R(x)) - P(x)R(x)(P'(x)+R'(x))}{(P(x)+R(x))^2}$$

Now assume $x^*$ is a point where $P(x^*) = R(x^*) = l$. Then

$$M'(x^*) = 2 \frac{(P'(x^*)l+lR'(x^*))2l - l^2(P'(x^*)+R'(x^*))}{4l^2} =$$
$$= \frac 12 (2(P'(x^*)+R'(x^*))-P'(x^*)+R'(x^*)) = \frac 12 (P'(x^*)+R'(x^*)) \neq 0$$

So in general the maximum of $M$ is *not* in a point where $P(x^*) = R(x^*)$.

---

You can see though that when additionally $P'(x^*)+R'(x^*) = 0$, then $M'(x^*)$ is a stationary point, which means that it can be a maximum (or a minimum - for that you need to investigate further).

In your picture, when the two lines cross, one is increasing more or less linearly, one is decreasing more or less linearly. This means that in your picture $P'(x^*)+R'(x^*) \approx 0$ which is why the maximum appears to be the intersection of the lines.

Comment: I don't see why you are so sure that 1/2(P′($x^∗$)+R′($x^∗$))≠0.

P is increasing, R is decreasing, so their derivatives will have opposite signs and could add up to zero. As you say, this can happen when both derivatives are zero, but also elsewhere.

Comment: @Blackjack $P'(x^*) + R'(x^*)$ is different than $0$ in *general*. Now, for some particular functions it can happen, but so what? You ask "Is the max of $M$ where $P$ and $R$ meet?" and the answer is "It depends on P and R, typically not, but it can happen". So if you are computing your measure for a certain pair of $P$ and $R$, you can never be sure that the maximum is there. You can compute it explicitly and realize that indeed that's where it is, but you cannot know it *before*, because *in general* $M'(x^*) \neq 0$

Comment: @Blackjack Also, I did not talk about the two derviatives being both zero. I said "one is increasing linearly", which means that the derivative is $1$. The other decreasing linearly, meaning derivative of $-1$. Hence the sum of the derivatives is zero, which corresponds to your graph. But it's just a coincidence, it's not true in general

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I see what you are saying now. I feel very very rusty. So my question actually was "in what circumstances could we be sure" and I'm wondering now, from what you have said, whether there is an answer along the lines of: "if the P and R curves are gentle, then the maximum of M will be close to the point where they cross".

Comment: @Blackjack Sure, if P in increasing with a certain constant slope (within a certain accuracy) and R is decreasing with the same slope (again, within a certain accuracy) then $P'+R'  \approx 0$ within (accuracy1 + accuracy2). Then when they meet you'll have $M'(x) \approx 0$. How useful this characterisation is? Depends on your application.